# Can any non-vertical line be translated such that it intersects a parabola exactly twice?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Given the parabola $y=ax^2+bx+c$ and the line $y=mx+d$, where $(a,b,m)\not=0$ and $(a,b,c,m,d)\in\mathbb R$, does there exist an $m$ where, for all $d$, there is at most one solution to this system of equations? Or, in other words, does $$ax^2+bx+c=mx+d\implies ax^2+(b-m)x+(c-d)=0$$ have two solutions for some $d$?

Comment: Will the close voter please explain why this is "missing context or other details"?

Comment: Can you please add what you've tried already and any particular difficulties you encountered? Maybe also add where you found this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That equation will have two solutions if and only if$$(b-m)^2-4a(c-d)>0.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Duh. How did I miss this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The composition of 2 translations is a translation. First translate the parabola to the form $y = ax^2.$ Then you can translate the line to $y = mx + \text{sgn}(a).$

Comment: How does $y=ax^2+bx+c$ translate to $y=ax^2$? I can see how it translates to $y=ax^2+bx$, but how can you drop the $bx$ just by sliding it?

Comment: @DonielF Recall the vertex form: $ax^2 + bx + c = a(x-h)^2 + k.$ Now you can translate by $(h, -k).$

Comment: Vertex form, vertex form... I must have had a really bad algebra class if I never learned this. I can see how they're equivalent, and it's a really useful tool to have when dealing with these kinds of problems.